# Access element of array inside object jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to fill a canvas with a color that's an element of an array inside an object and the element index should be *i* but the code seems to be wrong.
The variables inside *color1* are already declared and contain a string which is the hex value for the color.

```
var colorsObj = {
    color1: [orange,amber,apricot,tangerine,bittersweet,persimmon,salmon,peach,pumpkin]
}

function drawCanvas(color) {
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    $('.app').append('<canvas class="shadescolors" id="shade'+i+'"  width="100" height="100">');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('shade'+i);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth / 3;
    cc = canvas.width;
    radius = cc/2-10;
    canvas.height = canvas.width;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(cc/2, cc/2, cc/2-10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    alert(colorsObj.color[i]);
    context.fillStyle = colorsObj.color[i];
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#8A8A8A';
    context.stroke();
    }
}

drawCanvas('color1');
```

The alert doesn't fire either.

Comment: `colorsObj.color` is not the same as `colorsObj.color1`.

Comment: Your color object has a property which is an array named `color1`. You are trying to access the index of an array named `color` which doesn't exist. Secondly, your array contains a bunch of values which are probably all undefined. I think you mean to have them as strings `colors: ['orange, 'amber' ... etc ]` Because you are passing a string into your `drawCanvas` function, it looks like you're trying to access the colorObjects array, but you're using the wrong syntax. `colorObj['color1']` would work. But I think you kinda have this all wrong, you may want to look up JavaScript objects & arrays

Comment: You should use your browser console (F12) to look at JavaScript errors to help you figure out what might be causing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that you need to use `colorObj[color]` to get to your color list instead of `colorObj.color`, because you want to use the *value* of the `color` variable to select the specific color list within `colorObj`. (I assume you may later have a `color2` entry inside `colorObj`, etc., correct?)

Also you're missing the first element of the color list by starting your loop with `1`, and the `10` loop limit should use the `.length` of the color list instead of being hard coded.

You're missing a `var` on a couple of the variables inside the loop, and since you set `cc`, `canvas.width`, and `canvas.height` all to the same value you may as well do all that in one statement.

As a simplification tip, it isn't necessary to give your `canvas` element a sequential ID and use `getElementById()` to find it. Instead you can save a reference to the element when you create it and just use that.

I also took out the `width=` and `height=` in the HTML code for the `canvas` element; they are redundant since you are setting the width and height in your code.

Finally, please indent your code! :-)

So you might try something like this:

```
var colorsObj = {
    color1: [ orange,amber,apricot,tangerine,bittersweet,persimmon,salmon,peach,pumpkin ]
}

function drawCanvas( color ) {
    var colorList = colorsObj[color];
    for( var i = 0;  i < colorList.length;  i++ ) {
        var $canvas = $('<canvas class="shadescolors">').appendTo('.app');
        var canvas = $canvas[0];
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var cc = canvas.width = canvas.height = window.innerWidth / 3;
        var radius = cc/2-10;
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cc/2, cc/2, cc/2-10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        context.fillStyle = colorsList[i];
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = '#8A8A8A';
        context.stroke();
    }
}

drawCanvas('color1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the values in the color1 array strings or other variables? If they are strings this should be:

```
color1: ['orange','amber','apricot','tangerine','bittersweet','persimmon','salmon','peach','pumpkin']
```

Remember the first element in the array has index 0, so to fix your for loop I would do:

```
for(var i = 0; i < colorsObj.color1.length; i++)
```

There is also an error in your alert statement where you use `alert(colorsObj.color[i]);` instead of `alert(colorsObj.color1[i]);` (color1, not color)

Comment: On top of that, the `drawCanvas` function taking a color parameter, which is not really being used, but instead is the name of the wrong array is extra confusing things.